# How to use SynonymFilterFactory with ShingleFilterFactory in Solr?

Tags: solr, lucene

What I want to achieve is searching for 'deodorant spray' matches 'antiperspirant spray', 'deo spray' etc.

I'm using a SynonymFilterFactory to add synonyms at index time for deodorant, deo and antiperspirant. I can see this working correctly in the analyzer.

After this I'm running a ShingleFilterFactory (maxShingleSize="3") to split into combinations of words. This, again gives me the correct result, e.g. analysing 'test shingle phrase' gives:

- test
- test shingle
- test shingle phrase
- shingle
- shingle phrase
- phrase

Which is the desired result. The problem comes when I combine synonym terms with shingles. For example, searching for 'deodorant spray' should give me:

- deodorant spray
- deo spray
- antiperspirant spray

for all my synonyms. But what I actually see is:

- deodorant
- deodorant deo
- deodorant deo antiperspirant
- deo
- deo antiperspirant
- deo antiperspirant spray
- antiperspirant
- antiperspirant spray

Which clearly is making shingles from each of the synonym terms too. I've tried swapping the order of my filter factories but can't seem to get it to work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I should add I've got expand=true so that I don't have to do synonyms at query time. If I use expand=false then "deo spray" will be indexed as "deodorant spray" which is correct but requires me to also run the SynonymFilter at query time. According to the docs at http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.SynonymFilterFactory synonym expanding at index time is recommended.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you can do is to use synonym filter without expanding - the one that reduces all synonyms to the first in the list. Then you have to use it  at index time, as well as at query time.

Such approach **would not** cause problem described in the [documentation](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.SynonymFilterFactory), since you have to apply the filter also on the index.

> Consider the following scenario:
>
> - An index with a "text" field, which at query time uses the SynonymFilter with the synonym TV, Televesion and expand="true"
> - Many thousands of documents containing the term "text:TV"
> - A few hundred documents containing the term "text:Television"
>
> A query for text:TV will expand into (text:TV text:Television) and the lower docFreq for text:Television will give the documents that match "Television" a much higher score then docs that match "TV" comparably -- which may be somewhat counter intuitive to the client. Index time expansion (or reduction) will result in the same idf for all documents regardless of which term the original text contained.

However, you might still run into problems if you want to support multi-word synonyms as described in the documentation.

I do not know if shingles consisting of synonyms will affect search results anyhow, but if not, then only what it costs you is extra space in the index, so consider if it is something you want to save on.